# AngularJS Save Browse History

Tags: angularjs, browser, browser-history

I'm trying to solve a problem. I want that when a perform an action or function in the controller to be saved in the brose history. For example, I want to do this:

- Type something in a textbox.
- Click a link to call a function that will set the string I typed to a variable in $scope and save it at the browser history.
- Do the same as the previous step with a different value.
- If I click the "back" button from the browser, I want to display the first value I entered.

I have a very simple example of what I want but I don't know what do I have to add to be able to use the "back" and "forward" button from the browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/XMFua/

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you use angular's routing system, saving to the browser history will be taken care of for you.  To solve this problem I would probably use a combination of `$routeParam`'s and manual `$route` changes in your controller.

Comment: Is there a chance for you to explain me how can I do this, please? I think I'm still a newbie to angular.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`$location` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) to set the URL. I don't know how to make it work on jsFiddle, however the following should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/marcenuc/BSDxG/